# Connect to ssh on machine behind NAT with forwarded port

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I am struggling with connection to my Raspberry Pi behind NAT in my home from outside.
What I did until now:

1. I set in my router DDNS to have access for outside because my ISP giving me dynamic IP (let say it is: external.no-ip.org)
2. I set in my router in DHCP static IP (sing MAC address) for my Raspberry Pi (let say it is 192.168.1.155)
3. I forwarded port 50022 on my router to port 22 of 192.168.1.155 which is reserved for Raspberry Pi

Next I am trying SSH

`ssh pi@external.no-ip.org -p 50022` and I can not connect to SSH.

What I am doing wrong? I have tested and can ping external.no-ip.org and it have my IP. I have tested redirections and for sure 50022 is redirected to 22 on my raspberry PI.

Thank you for help.

BR
Arek

Comment: For the ssh response to arrive back the private IP should be SNATed a.k.a MASQUERADE

Comment: `pi@externail.no-ip.org` Doesn’t look like a valid hostname - `external.no-ip.org` is what you should use. Also, if you use `ping external.no-ip.org` does the hostname resolve to the correct IP address (of the WAN side of your router)?

Comment: Oh actually the other problem is going to be that you are mapping external port 50022 to pi port 22 - try making both port numbers the same port 22 or port 50022, if necessary changing your ssh service to use port 50022 (simplest to first try making the external port 22). Also, change one thing at a time and retest because if you change two things you won’t know which thing fixed the problem.

Comment: And make sure your pi firewall is allowing incoming on port 22 - you can check this on your local network.

Comment: Hi @barny, thank you for your suggestions. I am sorry, to fast pressed Enter. Will write full answer bellow.

Comment: Yes, when I am ping external.no-ip.org the host resolve to the external WAN IP.

Comment: I just changed redirection to the same (22) port. So now on my router every incoming request for port 22 is forwarded to internal Pi address (192.168.1.155)
I suppose the problem is that I a am wrongly using SSH. When I am connecting to Pi SSH in internal network I am using `ssh pi@192.168.1.155` and it working OK. So I thought from outside after port redirection it should be `ssh pi@external.no-ip.org` but it not working, no errors just after ~1 min time out error.

Comment: I am still wondering how to tell ssh to connect to pi@192.168.1.155 "on the" or "thru the" host external.no-ip.org

Comment: @ArekS Can you try to `telnet` at the port? `telnet external.no-ip.org 22` or `telnet external.no-ip.org 50022` depending on what's configured right now?

Comment: Thank you all for answers. It is shame for me to tell you what I missed when checking my connection. Silently my ISP put my router behind NAT, so now I can not reach it from the internet. I just call to my ISP and came back with dynamic external IP for me.
Thank again and I am sorry for mess. - Arek

Comment: Are you trying this command from inside your local network, or from outside? See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1730110/ssh-can-access-externally-but-not-from-the-local-network) for a related issue, where this works from outside, but not from inside.

Answer (score 0):

the easy way would be to simply install [dataplicity](https://www.dataplicity.com) on your pi, they let you use one pi for free, its basically a ssh service that lets you access your pi over the internet.

are you able to access the pi using the ddns from within your network, i have used ssh on many  linux computers like this and never had a problem oh and it could also be that your isp is blocking it.